# Transfer only custom installed fonts from Windows 7 to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-7, fonts

I am doing a clean reinstall of my system, and I wanted to transfer my custom fonts to the new system.

While I could just backup the entire "fonts" folder of the OS, as I understand that besides my fonts it also contains all the *default* system fonts, of which there is A LOT. **Is there a way to separate the default fonts from the non-default (my) fonts?**

I'm reluctant to just hit "install" on the entire folder in the new system due to the possibility of old outdated fonts from windows 7 replacing more modern versions in Win10 (if there's any), or some junk legacy fonts, that I won't ever use, contaminating the new system (That one isn't really a *technical problem*, but it would irk my OCD, to be honest).

Comment: Why don’t you just reinstall your custom fonts that are specifically compatible with Windows 10?  How you install fonts shortly after the release of Windows 10

Comment: I've been collecting these fonts for nearly a decade now. It's too chaotic and expansive for me to attempt to gather them anew.

Comment: While you certainly can just copy and paste the fonts that are not there by default. I have literally seen hundreds of questions on this website about making a system unable to boot due to custom fonts.  How you install custom fonts has indeed changed.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the list of standard Windows fonts in the Microsoft article
[Windows 10 font list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list).
These are the fonts that come with Windows 10 and that should not be overwritten.

However, there is a simple method for installing only Windows 7 fonts that are
not in Windows 10. Remember that the fonts folder is `C:\Windows\Fonts` in both.

The simplest method is to copy the `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder from Windows 7
to one of your folders, use a comparison program to compare it with the contents
of the Windows 10 folder. Install only the fonts that differ in name (not size
or date).

Comment: Can you suggest such a comparison program, please?

Comment: See the article [How to Compare the Contents of Two Folders and Synchronize them](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/compare-two-directories-files-find-differences/). You are looking for a tool where you can set the criteria to name-only. WinMerge is the tool I use, but there are others.